# Custom NER Spacy throwing IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python-3.x, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to create custom NER using Spacy but, while training, I am getting the following error:
*gold = GoldParse(doc, entities=entity_offsets)
  File "gold.pyx", line 565, in spacy.gold.GoldParse.**init**
IndexError: list index out of range*

Any idea as to how I can fix this?

The most common resolution that came up after doing some google search was to trim leading and trailing white spaces in the training data. So I used this code to trim them off. But still was of no use.

'''
invalid_span_tokens = re.compile(r'\s')

```
cleaned_data = []
for text, annotations in data:
    entities = annotations['entities']
    valid_entities = []
    for start, end, label in entities:
        valid_start = start
        valid_end = end
        while valid_start < len(text) and invalid_span_tokens.match(
                text[valid_start]):
            valid_start += 1
        while valid_end > 1 and invalid_span_tokens.match(
                text[valid_end - 1]):
            valid_end -= 1
        valid_entities.append([valid_start, valid_end, label])
    cleaned_data.append([text, {'entities': valid_entities}])
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Ah, so the words would be a keyword argument on the GoldParse object. This lets you specify the gold-standard tokenization, if it doesn't match spaCy's tokenization. Assuming your input looks like this:

```
text = 'helloworld'
words = ['hello', 'world']
tags = ['INTJ', 'NOUN']
```

You can do the following:

```
doc = Doc(text)
gold = GoldParse(doc, words=words, tags=tags)
nlp.update([doc], [gold])
```

Alternatively, you can also use the new "simple training style" and just pass in the text as a string, and the annotations as a dictionary:

```
nlp.update([text], [{'words': words, 'tags': tags}])
```

In general, we'd recommend using the simple style, as it removes one layer of abstraction, and lets you get rid of the Doc and GoldParse imports. But ultimately, the style you choose depends on your personal preference.